# Efficiently sort an array of integers when having extra information about the final sorted array

Tags: sorting

Suppose we have this array of integers called `data`

```
 3
 2
 4
 5
 2
```

Also we have the following array of the same size called `info`

```
 1
 4
 0
 2
 3
```

Each value of `info` represents an index on the first array. So for example the first value is `1` which means that in position `0` the final sorted array will have the value `data[info[0]]`.

By following this logic the final sorted array will be the following:

```
data[info[0]] => 2
data[info[1]] => 2
data[info[2]] => 3
data[info[3]] => 4
data[info[4]] => 5
```

I would like to make an *in place* sorting of the `data` array, without using any extra memory of size `N` where `N` is the size of the `data` array. In addition I would like the amount of total operations to be as small as possible.

I've been trying to think of a solution to my problem however I couldn't think of anything that wouldn't use extra memory. Keep in mind that these are my own restrictions for a system that I'm implementing, if these restrictions can't be kept then I will probably have to think of something else.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need the info array to remain intact after the sort (I'm guessing not since it's sorted)?

Comment: I don't need it to remain intact.

Comment: three answers, and no feedback from you? you did say that "Any ideas would be appreciated"? did any of the answers help you in any way? :)

Comment: hi Will, I was very busy with work these days and I just had the chance to check them out in detail, all of them are very helpful, however it's difficult to choose the best answer since all of them use a different but interesting at the same time approach to this problem.

Comment: great, is always good to be busy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `info` array need not remain intact, you can use that as additional storage and sort in `O(n)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int where = info[i];
    if (where == i) continue;
    info[i] = data[i];
    data[i] = i < where ? data[where] : info[where];
}
```

If an element of `data` is already in its correct place, we skip that index. Otherwise, remember the element in the `info` array, and write the correct element into `data`, fetching it from `data` if it comes from a larger index, and from `info` if it comes from a smaller index.

Of course that simple method requires the types of the `info` and `data` arrays to be the same, and in general does `3*n` copies.

If the `data` elements cannot be stored in the `info` array, we can follow the cycles in `info`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Check if this is already in the right place, if so mark as done
    if (info[i] == i) info[i] = -1;

    // Nothing to do if we already treated this index
    if (info[i] < 0) continue;

    // New cycle we haven't treated yet
    Stuff temp = data[i];    // remember value
    int j = info[i], k = i;
    while(j != i) {
        // copy the right value into data[k]
        data[k] = data[j];
        // mark index k as done
        info[k] = -1;
        // get next indices
        k = j;
        j = info[j];
    }
    // Now close the cycle
    data[k] = temp;
    info[k] = -1;
}
```

That does `n - F + C` copies of `data` elements, where `F` is the number of elements that already were in the right place (fixed points of the sorting permutation) and `C` is the number of cycles of length `> 1` in the sorting permutation. That means the number of copies is at most `3*n/2`.

Comment: why not simply `for i in 0..n-1 : info[i] := data[info[i]];` and then copy back element-wise from `info` to `data`? `2*n` copies total. Both arrays are of same size, both hold integers. (?)

Comment: Overcomplicating it ;) I was three-quarters occupied with the cycle-chasing when I wrote the first part.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply

```
for i in 0..n-1 : 
   info[i] := data[info[i]]
```

and `info` now holds the sorted array. If it must be in `data`, just copy it back, next:

```
for i in 0..n-1 : 
    data[i] := info[i]
```

`2*n` copies, overall.